# Using variables in multiple macros

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong here. Excel doesn't seem to set the variable value if I run the second macro before the first one. I would like to set the values just once and use them in multiple macros. I have 6 macros that will be using the same values. The code included below is a short code I use to test.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Test As String

Sub sub1()

Test = "Test"
MsgBox Test

End Sub

Sub sub2()

MsgBox Test

End Sub
```

This is the popup i get if the second macro is executed before the first one.

[image]

Comment: You can use Public variables; you "dim" them over your first code and they'll be open for every macro to be used. Ex : Public Constant gravity as double = 9.8

Comment: If you run the sub2 first, Test has not been assigned a value and so will be an empty string. You can call subs from each other.

Comment: @SJR So i created another macro and name it "setvalue" and call it in every macros I have. That worked but are there cleaner ways to do this?

Comment: If you know the value in advance you could use a constant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-constants You can't then change its value though. Or have one master macro which calls the others, depends on the details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @PatatesPilées i tried Public Test as String = "Some Text" and got a compile error. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Aaron do it in 2 lines for strings : Public Test as String (next line) Test = "Test"  (Like Lewis answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the second macro from the first. Otherwise Test will not be assigned a value.

You can read about scope [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Scope.aspx).

```
Dim Test As String

Sub sub1()

Test = "Test"
MsgBox Test
sub2 'or call sub2

End Sub
```

Or you can use a [`Constant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/const-statement), e.g.

`Public Const Test As String = "Test"`

Comment: adding Const Test As String = "Test" in Declaration worked! Please post your answer and I will accept. I can accept this one too if you prefer.

Comment: OK, have updated my answer. Note the stuff about scope in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

(see my edit below - the original answer doesn't answer the question you asked properly)

You can set it as a public variable

```
Option Explicit

Public Test As String

Sub sub1()

    Test = "Test"
    MsgBox Test

End Sub

Sub sub2()

    MsgBox Test

End Sub
```

Or call sub2 from sub1 with a parameter

```
Sub sub1()

    Test = "Test"
    MsgBox Test
    'call the second sub with the Test variable here
    sub2 Test

End Sub

Sub sub2(test as string)

    MsgBox test

End Sub
```

or have Sub1 be a function and return the value

```
Function sub1()

    Test = "Test"
    MsgBox Test
    'call the second sub with the Test variable here
    sub1 = Test

End Function

Sub sub2()
    test = sub1()
    MsgBox test

End Sub
```

EDIT :

Or you could wrap it all in another sub so you are able to define the public variable

```
Public Test as string 

Sub sub1()

    MsgBox Test

End Sub

Sub sub2()

    MsgBox Test

End Sub

Sub run()
    Test = "Test"
    sub1()
    sub2()

End Sub
```

Comment: But if you call the second sub first OP will have the same issue as above.

Comment: To be fair i didn't read his question properly until you wrote this!! My bad

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable to keep its value for the whole excel session (i.e. a static variable) use the `Global` keyword

```
Global Test As String
```

Remember, one of your procedures must assign a value to it. Otherwise it will have a value of `""`